# Convert inputstream to pdf to byte array

Tags: java, salesforce, mule

i created a mule flow which accepts a file as inputstream and convert into byte array and attach that file to the particular SalesForce case.
Can it possible that i could convert the file(coming as inputstream) to the pdf format and attach to Salesforce case.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is a special format so directly it will not create PDF. You can use libraries like Apache FOP or iText to create PDF output.